# JSON TableView Swift Error

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

I'm trying to populate a tableview with this JSON URL. I validated the URL, and it works fine. My code is at fault. I have a 'Repository.swift' file with a class inside. Here's my code: I can't resolve the issue.

```
var repositories = [Repository]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL) {
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                for item in reposArray {
                    repositories.append(Repository(json: item))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.repositories.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = repositories[indexPath.row].Event
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = repositories[indexPath.row].Hasta

    return cell
}
```

Comment: call can throw but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Comment: 3 errors 1)'let' declarations cannot be computed properties 2) Cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary? 3) 'is' test is always true.. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add try catch

I fixed your code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL) {
        do{
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: .MutableContainers)
            if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {

                for item in reposArray {

                    // repositories.append(Repository(json: item))


                }
            }
        }catch {
        //do whatever
        }

    }
}
```

Kindly try it.

Comment: 3 errors 1)'let' declarations cannot be computed properties 2) Cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary? 3) 'is' test is always true.. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: thanks.. that bit seems ok now... but it's caused one other error: "definition conflicts with previous value" with this line:                        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

Comment: @DonDraper that is because your code doesn't have correct close brackets `}`, please try to fix that, and if you want, put your whole viewcontroller and i try to help

Comment: fixed the brackets:  immutable probable for this line : "for item in reposArray {"

Comment: @DonDraper that is because you are not using the variable `item` inside the for. Either use the variable, or replace it by `_`

Comment: @DonDraper write a new question with your new problem